# Python add new element to existing JSON File

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to append some data into a JSON file inside python.
It should add the CVE-ID into my customer JSON file.

I wasn't able to solve this by myself. If I print my dict after appending it shows the expected result.
But it seems, that the file will not be written after the append. I have also tried to use `json.dump()` after the "appending-line" - but also without success.

At the moment my code looks like this:

```
with open("test.json", "r+") as customerdata:
    customers_json = json.load(customerdata)

# some other code here...

if cve["cve"]["CVE_data_meta"]["ID"] not in customer["customer"]["already-sent-cve"]:
                customers_json["customers"][0]["customer"]["already-sent-cve"].append(cve["cve"]["CVE_data_meta"]["ID"])
```

My JSON file looks like this:

```
    {
        "customers":[
            {
                "customer":{
                    "id":"1",
                    "company-name":"test GmbH",
                    "alert-email":"xyz@googlemail.com",
                    "using":[
                        "xxx",
                        "xyz"
                    ],
                    "already-sent-cve":[
                        "CVE-2013-3738"
                        # here new CVE
                    ]
                }
            },
        {
            "customer":{
                "id":"2",
                  ...
          }
    ]
}
```

FYI: There is another JSON file with the CVE's from which file I'm collecting the data.

Any suggestions how to solve this?

Regards.

### EDIT:

Was able to solve this:

```
with open("test.json", "w") as customerdata:
    customers_json["customers"][0]["customer"]["already-sent-cve"].append(cve["cve"]["CVE_data_meta"]["ID"])
    json.dump(customers_json, customerdata, indent=2)
```

Comment: can you please share code where you are using ```json.dump```

Comment: Your edit should be posted as an answer -- not as an update to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write the data back to the file:

```
with open('test.json', 'w') as customerdata:
    json.dump(customers_json, customerdata)
```

Comment: So but I need still the append operation? 
I'm not sure how I can only write back the new element or is it only possible to wirte back a complete JSON file (and not just add the needed element)?

Comment: you need to write back the complete JSON file

Comment: Ahh, got it. This was my mistake. I thought I'm able to write back only a specific value. Now it seems to be working. Thanks.